# Persisting a massive, distributed hashset in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, distributed, hashset, serverless

**The problem**

I want to write an application in which the user is able to enter any string 128 characters or less, and the application will tell the user whether they have entered that string in the past.

It is expected that there may be massive string counts per-user, on the order of millions, as well as tens-of-thousands of users.

**The question**

It seems to me that DynamoDB would be a reasonable choice to solve this problem, with the partition key as the user ID and the sort key as the string in question.

Is this reasonable? Are there other established patterns for serverless hashsets?

Comment: The solutions seems solid, except that it might make sense to hash the string and use that as the sort key and toss the string. Unless you need to persist the string itself, in which case just use the string. [Partition and sort key limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Limits.html#limits-partition-sort-keys) give you 1024 bytes for your sort key so your string isn't to big to be used.

Answer (score 2):

I propose a different solution that I think will work much better on Dynamo.

Rather than using the UserId as a partition key, and the "User String" as the sort key, do the opposite: use the "User String" as a partition key and the UserId as a sort key.

The chances that the same string will be used by multiple people will be relatively small and that will give you really good distribution in the key space - which is exactly what DynamoDB is all about.

The query to determine if the string has ever been used in the past by the same user doesn't change at all - it's still a single `GetItem` operation.

And you don't need to hash the user string. DynamoDB will hash behind the scenes for you anyway. And since you said the strings will be 128 characters or less then you really have nothing to be concerned about size-wise.

The only reason you may consider hashing is if you'd like to preserve anonymity. In that case, read through this article explaining [how to use k-anonimity to protect users privacy](https://blog.cloudflare.com/validating-leaked-passwords-with-k-anonymity/). Even if you don't care about that use case, the article is a must-read in my opinion!